# How do I remove the information section available below the comment box?

Tags: 7, comments

As shown in the image, below the comment text-area there is an information section I do not want to show. How do I remove the part highlighted in red?

[image: Druapl core comment format]

I want the comments to appears as they do on StackExchange, where user just have a text-area for entering their comments.

Comment: That is the part selecting which input format the users are using. Why would you take it off?

Comment: In terms of look and feel, it appearance very odd, you can see the stakexchange's comment box, clean and clear. hence I need that way in drupal 7.

Comment: Stack Exchange doesn't allow to use more than one input format; that is the reason it doesn't have that part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Simplify](https://www.drupal.org/project/simplify) module is what you are looking for. Besides hiding the text format selection, it has a few more settings to hide, which really "simplifies" the user interface.

> Simplify allows particular fields to be hidden from the user interface. This helps to de-clutter forms and present a more user-friendly experience to content editors.

Answer (score 1):

> Stack Exchange doesn't allow to use more than one input format

You can use the better formats module to allow 1 format, just like SE, which will get rid of the text format box.

#### [Better Formats](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_formats)

> - Set allowed text formats per field.
> - Set default order of text formats per field.
> - Hide format tips per role.
> - Hide more format tips link per role.
> - Hide format selection per role per entity.
> - Currently only works on Field API fields on fieldable entities implementing core style text processing. The good thing is that is
>   most things in core and contrib.

The rest you will have to css `{ display none: }` it away

If anyone knows a better way, I'd like to hear it.

Actually, reading this I just realised there is a **hide format tips per role** :O

Perhaps that will get rid off the rest? :O